# Select rows through columns value using command line

Tags: awk, command-line

I have a .tsv file with this format:

```
Year    Region  Subfunction                     Total
2007    Midwest General administration          4,652,314.25
2007    Midwest Child and teenager assistance   3,066,433.22 
2007    Midwest Basic assistance                45,653,414.66
2007    Midwest International cooperation       985,859.30
```

How can I print all rows using two columns condition, for example, print all rows where year == 2009 and region == south?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$1==2009 && tolower($2)=="south"' file
```

if you want to print the header, you can

```
awk 'NR==1 || (...)'
```

Comment: `tolower($2)` was a nice touch :-) PlusOne

Comment: Thank you @karafka! Perfect!

Comment: @karafka How could I keep the header (Year, Region, Subfunction, Total) in the result?

Comment: nit-pick: add `-F'\t'` since the OP did say it's a TSV file so for all we know a Region in their real data could be "Northern Europe" or something else with a space in it. Yes, it would be nice if cases like that were included in the example if they can occur but in this case the OP didn't even include the region (s)he wants to find in  the sample!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -nE '/^2007[[:blank:]]+[sS]outh/p' file.tsv
```

also should do it. This assumes the year appears as full 4 digits in the beginning (note `^`)